# What are the similarities and differences between the LDS and RLDS D&C?

Tags: lds, doctrine-and-covenants, community-of-christ

[The Community of Christ (formerly RLDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_Christ), has more sections to [their Doctrine and Covenants](https://app.box.com/shared/x7067y9dqo) –**163 sections**. This is 25 more than what's in the [LDS Doctrine and Covenants](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc?lang=eng).

I notice also that many of the scriptures from sections written by Joseph Smith have been omitted by the Community of Christ.

Without creating a long list answer, can someone explain what's in the RLDS D&C that isn't in the LDS D&C? And what the RLDS have removed or changed from the D&C that Joseph Smith wrote?

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the link below and see the table below to determine what is the difference between the LDS Doctrine & Covenants and the RLDS Doctrine and Covenants.  One of the differences is that after Brigham Young left with a group of saints the RLDS church was organized and their leaders Thomas Burdick, Warren Parish and Sylvester Smith began to write more sections in the Doctrine and covenants. As far as why the community of Christ Ommitted some of the scriptures, its probably because it wasn't in line with their doctrines.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_and_Covenants

Hopefully this wasn't too long.

Comment: Too long. Probably too short, if anything. Welcome to the site. We're happy to have you here.

Comment: Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.